# PHP Alternative Syntax for comments

Tags: php, syntax, comments

I know there is an alternative syntax for control structures(
[PHP Alternate Syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)
). Is there an equivalent for PHP comments? Mainly so comments do not show up in view source.
Something like this perhaps.

```
<?php /* ?>
<h1>THIS WILL NOT SHOW UP ON VIEW SOURCE</h1>
<?php */ ?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Um... Last I checked the code you gave here will produce no output because of the comment...

Comment: /* anything between these two bookends is considered a comment */
# and prefixing a line with a hash also comments out the line

Comment: @DevlshOne # and // do not affect ?> though. /*...*/ does.

Comment: Good point, although just realised it doesn't really make sense what I am asking and is achieved by just doing.
<?php /*
<h1>THIS WILL NOT SHOW UP ON VIEW SOURCE</h1>
*/ ?>
Which is shorter any way.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP could have easily tested their code themselves

Comment: @johnsnails As I said in my initial comment, the code you have given works as you want it to. It will not show up in `View Source`. If it does, then it's because you're not running it through a server, or your server isn't executing PHP.

Comment: @Kolink point taken. I'm an idiot for not realizing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have there actually works as expected; alternatively, you can use this as well:

```
<?php /*
<h1>THIS WILL NOT SHOW UP ON VIEW SOURCE</h1>
*/ ?>
```

To guard against other code that may appear in between, you could consider using normal control structures with a falsy condition:

```
<?php if (0): ?>
<h1>THIS WILL NOT SHOW UP ON VIEW SOURCE</h1>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: @doitlikejustin Any falsy condition, so `null`, `''`, `array()` would all work :)